# Remove 1px scroll bar offset (swing)

Tags: java, swing, border, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm developing a Swing app and I'm trying to make it as clean as possible and I would like to know if it's possible to remove the 1px offset that appears on the bottom and bottom right sides when using scrollbars:

[image]

I know I'm nitpicking here but I'd really like to know if I can remove this. Also this offset is not my fault because it seems to appear whenever we use scrollbars see: http://www.zentut.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/jscrollbar.gif and http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/SwingScrollBarExample.PNG

Comment: Try using a different PLAF.

Comment: Sort of fixed it using a plain BasicScrollBarUI, it looks better than the metal ones in my app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of fixed it using a plain BasicScrollBarUI, it looks better than the metal ones in my app anyway.

```
    scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI());
    scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUI(new BasicScrollBarUI());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but here is how I solved it:

```
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```